# Can't determine type for tag '<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a small Android app which involves Google Maps (created with Android Studio by selecting the Google Maps activity template).

It works fine on my test phone, but when I build a signed APK and install it on another phone, the map is blank.

After some Googling, perhaps the cause of the problem is because I'm using the wrong key.

I have this line in google_maps_api.xml:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Change that into:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Android Studio complains:
Error: Can't determine type for tag ''
[image]

Pardon the screenshot. For unknown reasons, the whole error message cannot be displayed properly on SO. How to solve this?

Comment: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />`  should be in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside application tag

Comment: @ManoharReddy is right meta data should be in androidmanifest file inside application tag. and for signed apk you have to make new map api key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta-data should be placed in `AndroidManifest.xml` file witinh  ***application*** tag.